# Heatsink for Quad core Xeon that draws same power as Dual core?

Tags: central-processing-unit

I have a Dell Precision 490 that has two LGA771 sockets and only one occupied socket - with a Dual core E5130 Xeon CPU running 2.0GHz rated at 80W TDP and it has on it a 80mm passive heatsink.

As the faster Quad core E5345 is also rated at 80W does that mean I could use a similar heatsink if I put one in the spare socket?

There's not any more room in the case for a heatsink bigger than 80mm, so I figure the TDP of the CPU determines the "class" of heatsink I need.

Answer (score 2):

The E5130 was rated at [65W TDP](http://ark.intel.com/products/27216) not 80, but you could at one time buy them with E5335's in them and they have a [TDP of 80](http://ark.intel.com/products/28443), as did the [E5345](http://ark.intel.com/products/28032) so that'll be fine with the same heatsink too.

You should also be able to fit an E5350, though they're hard/impossible to find.

Oh and I'd strongly suggest you update your BIOS to the latest version whatever way you go.